# Sql selection using between operator

Tags: mysql, sql, select

In my database table there are two fields named salary_to and salary_from.Now in  front end of my website user can enter a salary in an input field say 20000.Now i wanna perform a check in the database that if any row have salaryto and salaryfrom between which the value '20000' lies.
My desired algo looks like something like this

```
 SELECT all ROW where salaryto is less than 20000 and salaryfrom is greater than 20000
```

Can i use the between operator to perform this kind of filterring or i just ave to use >,< operator to this?
Provided that I'm using mysql database for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The between operator is `INCLUSIVE` meaning it includes the START and END Value. While `< >` are exclusive.

```
SELECT *
FROM  tableName
WHERE salaryto < 20000 and salaryfrom > 20000
```

So the rows that are fetched here are with `salaryto` value of 19999 and below AND `salaryfrom` value of 20001 and above, assuming that it increases by 1.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this:**

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE 2000 BETWEEN salary_to AND salary_from
```

**But this is Recommended:**

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE (salary_to < 2000) and (salary_from > 2000)
```

Comment: The first statement is running successfully and giving proper output in my program but i cant understand why you said that the second statement is recomended?

Comment: I always try to make the code easy to understand and most of the people are aware of 2nd method so I recommend to use it.